# Django: Why can I reverse a URL in the template but not in a view?

Tags: django, django-urls

There's some weird stuff happing with the URL reversal code in django 1.4.

I have a view called `settings.views.app_view`. I have viewed the page by typing in the URL manually to verify that the basic URL pattern is working.

```
url(r'^app/$', 'settings.views.app_view', name='settings_app_view'),
```

I have reversed the URL in a template and it works.

```
{% url settings_app_view %}
```

So, the URL pattern works, and I can call get the URL in a template, click the link and view the correct page.

So why can't I get the URL in a view using reverse()? All the code is clearly there, and not only that, it's clearly configured and working correctly as I've seen the page and reversed the URL in a template.

I have to be missing something small; does anyone know what it is?

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /settings/app/
Exception Value:    Could not import settings.views.app_view. View does not exist in module settings.views.

# The highlighted code
url = reverse("settings_app_view")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where exactly in your code does reverse() get executed? If reverse() gets executed during importing the python file, you can get a recursive import. Unfortunately a recursive import can have different results: AttributeError can happen on modules that should have this attribute....

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy

Comment: Yes, you are completely and utterly correct. I was putting that reverse() outside of a view definition as it was just filler for a couple of views. Moving it inside the definitions cleared everything up. | I'll read up on "lazy reverse django", thanks.